# AS3 return dropped object to initial location

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, drag-and-drop

I am using codes from http://hub.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-drag-and-drop-puzzle-in-actionscript-30--active-2920 to make a drag and drop decoration game. I am trying to make it so that when the dropped object is dragged out of target location (which is an outline of the shape in my case), it goes back to initial location... basically reversing the drag and drop. I've been messing around with really random codes and so far this line is the closest to what I want but I don't think the code is right and also it doesnt return to initial location, it just goes to the side of the stage.

so, I added the else if line to stopDragObject which got the object to be removed from target location, but it randomly goes to the side of the stage, and not initial location:

```
private function stopDragObject(evt:MouseEvent):void {
        if (evt.target.hitTestObject(getChildByName(evt.target.name + "Target"))) {
            evt.target.x = getChildByName(evt.target.name + "Target").x;
            evt.target.y = getChildByName(evt.target.name + "Target").y;
            
        }  else if (evt.target.x = null) {
            evt.target.x = xPos;
            evt.target.y = yPos;
        }
        
        evt.target.stopDrag();
    }
```

---

#### Solved

after reading the lesson from below,  I ended up with this and it works perfectly! (not exactly the way like the lesson but at least it works...)

```
private function stopDragObject(evt:MouseEvent):void {
        if (evt.target.hitTestObject(getChildByName(evt.target.name + "Target"))) {
            evt.target.x = getChildByName(evt.target.name + "Target").x;
            evt.target.y = getChildByName(evt.target.name + "Target").y;
            
        }  else {
            evt.target.x = getChildByName(evt.target.name + "Int").x;
            evt.target.y = getChildByName(evt.target.name + "Int").y;
        }
        
        evt.target.stopDrag();
    }
```

I added a initial object so the object could only be either at target or initial :)

Comment: To mark a question as solved, you are to press a "tick" under the answer provided that makes your question solved, if any. I see there is such an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I will try to teach neither provide code.

Lets draw two rectangles:

```
var s1:Sprite = new Sprite()
var s2:Sprite = new Sprite()
with (s1)
{
    graphics.beginFill(0xfcaaaa, .7)
    graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 400, 400)
    graphics.endFill()
}
with (s2)
{
    graphics.beginFill(0x00aaaa, .7)
    graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 30, 30)
    graphics.endFill()
}
addChild(s1)
addChild(s2)
```

Is't that simple? You see that `s1` is much bigger than `s2` (dimentions: `400, 400` vs `30, 30` ) Now place `s2` to the center of our big `s1`:

```
s2.x = 200;
s2.y = 200;
```

We will use `s1` for the boundaries of `s2` movings.

This code is a simplest solution for dragging our `s2` rectangle (`Sprite`):

```
s2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onDown)
s2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onUp)

function onDown(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    (e.currentTarget as Sprite).startDrag();
}

function onUp(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    (e.currentTarget as Sprite).stopDrag();
}
```

Now, the basic solution for returning our `Sprite` to the starting position: `hitTestObject` will return true, if `Sprite s2` is still located in the area of `Sprite s1`. More helpful functions [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Sprite.html). Lets check it. Change `onUp` function this way:

```
function onUp(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    var s:Sprite = (e.currentTarget as Sprite);
    s.stopDrag();
    if (!s.hitTestObject(s1))
    {
        s.x = 200;
        s.y = 200;
    }
}
```

You see that now `s2` gets returned to the starting position if it gets dragged out from the area of `s1`.

---

**Now the main part:**

What to do, if you can't predict the starting position of the object? Now, when we know how to deal with already known coordinates, this is the challange. I assume that there are several implementations of this functionality exist. One of the best way is to set additional parameters e.g. `startingX` and `startingY` for the dragging object when starting drag. E.g. in our example when `onDown` function gets called. I guess you dealing with `Sprite`s or `MovieClip`s and don't have the ability to do this.

Lets go another way and use `Dictionary` object. `Dictionary` is some kind of traditional `Hash Map` with the ability to use objects as keys.

> Hash map is kind of storage, where you can put any value mapped by a key, provided by you. In actionscript 3 we have `Object` as a limited implementation of Hash Map. Why use it? In two words because it's simple and fast. But with `Object` we can't use other `Objects` as keys, only strings ints numbers etc..

```
var sites:Object = new Object();
sites['stackoverflow'] = "http://stackoverflow.com/"
trace(sites.stackoverflow) // outputs-> http://stackoverflow.com/
```

With `Dictionary` we can use Objects as keys. 
Lets create it:

```
var startCoordinates:Dictionary = new Dictionary();
```

To save coordinates, we need `x` and `y` property.

---

FYI: `new Object()` is equivalent of `{}`

```
var capitals:Object = new Object();
capitals['Italy'] = 'Rome';
```

is equivalent of

```
var capitals:Object = {Italy: 'Rome'};
```

---

To save current position we will use this code:

```
var s:Sprite = (e.currentTarget as Sprite);
startCoordinates[s] = { x: s.x, y: s.y };
```

**And the whole code in our example will look like this:**

```
var s1:Sprite = new Sprite()
var s2:Sprite = new Sprite()
addChild(s1)
addChild(s2)
with (s1)
{
    graphics.beginFill(0xfcaaaa, .7)
    graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 400, 400)
    graphics.endFill()
}
with (s2)
{
    graphics.beginFill(0x00aaaa, .7)
    graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 30, 30)
    graphics.endFill()
}
s2.x = 200;
s2.y = 200;
s2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onDown)
s2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onUp)

var startCoordinates:Dictionary = new Dictionary()

function onDown(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    var s:Sprite = (e.currentTarget as Sprite);
    startCoordinates[s] = { x: s.x, y: s.y };
    s.startDrag();
}

function onUp(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    var s:Sprite = (e.currentTarget as Sprite);
    s.stopDrag();
    if (!s.hitTestObject(s1))
    {
        s.x = startCoordinates[s].x;
        s.y = startCoordinates[s].y;
    }
    delete startCoordinates[s];
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this, even though i didn't use the way you taught but it helped me think through how it would work

Comment: If this successfully answered your question, be sure to mark it as the accepted answer (by clicking the check mark near the top-left of the question).